# Four Color Theorem Disproof Attempt

Tags: logic, graph-theory, coloring

I was wondering, where I made a mistake in this attempt to disprove the four color map theorem. I hope that you smart folks can help me out.
I already apologize, if the tags are wrong. I am not really a math specialist.

[image: second attempt]

Comment: Make region 1 cyan and region 3 black, then you don't need orange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 5=1 and 6=3.

Comment: @Somos That might be the worst best closing reason ever.

Comment: What about the second attempt?

Comment: As Somos says, make 5,1 the same colour and 6,3 the same colour. Then you have only 4 colours. However, it is rude to change the question so that answers that were already given and accepted no longer make sense.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed myself that I made a fundamental and critical thinking error. Thank you guys very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that your third drawing is the one you are talking about:

You can color area 5 yellow and area 3 black, so there is no cyan anymore.

Comment: You meant orange, not yellow, right? If not, you would remove cyan but add yellow, which still makes 5 colors.

Comment: Yes orange haha